# How can I insert background image in my java desktop application?

Tags: java

I wanted to add set Background in my attached application, but it's not working out correctly for me. I've attached the whole source code + a screenshot of how I wanted the background to be in my application. Can anyone help me with this?

**Screenshot**:

[image: just an example]

[Source Code](http://wordpresstiger.com/Stackoverflow/) (Specifically GUI Menu)

Comment: No source code for me, sorry.

Comment: Please do not use [link shorteners](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113658/no-url-shorteners) or [signatures](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed). Please embed images and try to reduce the code to a [short, self contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/) that you can include as a code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to go through all your source - but it sounds like you want to set a background image on a panel.

You do that by overriding the panels paint code.

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics grphcs) {
    grphcs.drawImage(background, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
}
```

Where background is:

```
private final Image background;
```

and in your constructor:

```
    background = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("FILENAME.jpg"));
```